# How do I align a dropdown menu below a <div>?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

When I hover over "*Dropdown >*", the dropdown menu appears at the left side below the top bar. How do I align it just below "*Dropdown >*"?

Note that I am trying to do this with only CSS and HTML.

My Code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}
.top-container {
  margin-top: 7px;
}
/* Code for drop-down list */

.dropdown {
  margin-left: 100px;
  display: inline;
  color: #FFF;
}
.dropdown_list {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
}
.dropdown_list li {
  background: yellow;
}
.dropdown:hover {
  background: #333;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown_list,
.dropdown_list:hover {
  display: block;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="top-container">
      <div class="dropdown">Dropdown &#10097;
        <ul class="dropdown_list">
          <li>item 1</li>
          <li>item 2</li>
          <li>item 3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Why remove the [tag:drop-down-menu] tag?

Comment: Hm, I felt like it is not particularly useful, if you think otherwise, please add it again. I am sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `.dropdown`  from `inline` to `inline-block`:

```
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**Snippet:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}
.top-container {
  margin-top: 7px;
}
/* Code for drop-down list */

.dropdown {
  margin-left: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
}
.dropdown_list {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
}
.dropdown_list li {
  background: yellow;
}
.dropdown:hover {
  background: #333;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown_list,
.dropdown_list:hover {
  display: block;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="top-container">
      <div class="dropdown">Dropdown &#10097;
        <ul class="dropdown_list">
          <li>item 1</li>
          <li>item 2</li>
          <li>item 3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: nice, with this solution, Can we remove `position:absolute` from `.dropdown_list` ?

Comment: Thanks.  The submenu overlaps the main menu when you remove `position:absolute`.  But there may be other styles that can now be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Add `position:relative` to class `.dropdown` now your `.dropdown_list` is relative to the `.dropdown` you can use `top left right bottom` to place your `.dropdown_list` as you want.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}
.top-container {
  margin-top: 7px;
}
/* Code for drop-down list */

.dropdown {
  margin-left: 100px;
  display: inline;
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown_list {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
.dropdown_list li {
  background: yellow;
}
.dropdown:hover {
  background: #333;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown_list,
.dropdown_list:hover {
  display: block;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="top-container">
      <div class="dropdown">Dropdown &#10097;
        <ul class="dropdown_list">
          <li>item 1</li>
          <li>item 2</li>
          <li>item 3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative` to `.dropdown` and `left:0` to `.dropdown_list`

```
.dropdown {
    margin-left: 100px;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;/*add this*/
    color: #FFF;
}

.dropdown_list {
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    color: red;
    left: 0; /*add this*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply the `left-margin` to the container and set `position: relative` for the popup menu.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/jt83vj28/